# Translating the content of a html paragraph

Tags: html, translation, google-translate

The admin side of our website has a paragraph that is generated (so no way of knowing the content beforehand).

The content can be in different languages. I would like to display the translation of this paragraph into a different paragraph. Preferably using google translate.

Comment: Is it really necessary to include this everywhere: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and there: *Explain how you encountered the problem you're trying to solve, and any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself.* Probably, that's why.

Answer (score 0):

You get downvoted cause we are not here to do all the code, you have to try somethink or find solution on google before post your problem...

This is a working solution to translate a define div with google translate api, you need an API Key before try :

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?key=YOUR_GOOGLE_KEY"></script>
<div id="languages"><p>
    <a href="?lang=en" rel="en">English</a> / <a href="?lang=es" rel="es">Spanish</a> / <a href="?lang=it" rel="it">Italian</a> /
    <a href="?lang=fr" rel="fr">French</a>
</p></div>

<div id="languageBlock">
    <p>Lights go out and I can't be saved <br />
    Tides that I tried to swim against  <br />
    Brought me down upon my knees  <br />
    Oh I beg, I beg and plead </p>

    <p>Singin', come out if things aren't said  <br />
    Shoot an apple off my head  <br />
    And a, trouble that can't be named  <br />
    Tigers waitin' to be tamed </p>

    <p>Singing, yooooooooooooo ohhhhhh  <br />
    Yoooooooooooo ohhhhhh </p>

    <p>Home, home, where I wanted to go <br /> 
    Home, home, where I wanted to go  <br />
    Home, home, where I wanted to go  <br />
    Home, home, where I wanted to go</p>
</div>
```

Comment: How would I make it so that its immediately translated into my preferred language without me having to click on the link?